# Optimize Mysql UNION query for faster loading time

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am a beginner with mysql and i need some help in speeding up the following query. I am also a beginner when it comes to INDEXES and I don't quite understand how to add and use them. 
If anyone could please help me speed this query up I would deeply appreciate it.
At the moment the query takes ~10s to load.

Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 10.2243 sec)

```
SELECT `location2` AS `location` , '2' AS `number`
FROM `properties`
WHERE `price_from`
BETWEEN 0
AND 999999
AND `country` = 'france'
UNION SELECT `location3` AS `location` , '3' AS `number`
FROM `properties`
WHERE `price_from`
BETWEEN 0
AND 999999
AND `location2` = 'france'
UNION SELECT `location4` AS `location` , '4' AS `number`
FROM `properties`
WHERE `price_from`
BETWEEN 0
AND 999999
AND `location3` = 'france'
UNION SELECT `location5` AS `location` , '5' AS `number`
FROM `properties`
WHERE `price_from`
BETWEEN 0
AND 999999
AND `location4` = 'france'
UNION SELECT `location6` AS `location` , '6' AS `number`
FROM `properties`
WHERE `price_from`
BETWEEN 0
AND 999999
AND `location5` = 'france'
```

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry. I already plan on normalizing the data but for the moment I am looking to optimize the stated query for faster loading time. Any idea on that?

Comment: Yes. Normalize the data.

Comment: This query is bad on every level. Go straight for the refactoring of the DB instead of patching this "thing".

Answer (score 0):

Don't splay an array across columns.  Instead, have another table with as many rows as needed.

With that change, you can avoid the `UNION` and we can discuss how to optimize the `JOIN` that that will need.